# Argument out of range for 9th and 10th items in gridview

Tags: gridview, data-binding, webforms, multiview

I'm getting an argument out of range exception in the row rowdatabound event when clicking the edit button, but only for the 9th and 10th items, regardless of the data (same for any page).

The error occurs here.

```
DropDownList DropDownList_QuantityType = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList_QuantityType");
```

This is the rowdatabound event.

```
protected void GridView_BidItemTypeTables_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
        {
            DropDownList DropDownList_QuantityType = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList_QuantityType");
            DropDownList_QuantityType.SelectedValue = GridView_BidItemTypeTables.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
            DropDownList DropDownList_FHWA = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList_FHWA");
            DropDownList_FHWA.SelectedValue = GridView_BidItemTypeTables.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[2].ToString();
        }
    }
```

PageSize is set to 10, so I do not understand why the [8] and [9] item would be an argument out of range exception.

I attempted changing PageSize to 8, and all 8 items worked fine. When I changed PageSize to 11, the last 3 items failed instead of the last 2.

Here is the view in the aspx page.

```
<asp:View ID="View_BidItemTypeTables" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div style="width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: auto;">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView_BidItemTypeTables" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Records" DataKeyNames="GUID, QuantityTypeGuid,FHWA" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10"
                    CssClass="gridview" Width="50%" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView_BidItemTypeTables_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView_BidItemTypeTables_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView_BidItemTypeTables_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="GridView_BidItemTypeTables_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_BidItemTypeTables_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView_BidItemTypeTables_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button_EditTypeTables" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible="true" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button_SaveTypeTables" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" Visible="true" OnClick="Button_SaveTypeTables_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" /><asp:Button ID="Button_CancelTypeTables" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" Visible="true" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_Code" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Code" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_Code" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Code is Required." ControlToValidate="TextBox_Code" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_CodeGrid" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Code" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup = "ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxCodeValidatorBidItem_Grid" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_Description" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Description" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_DescriptionGrid" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Code" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup = "ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxDescriptionValidatorBidItem_Grid" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QuantityType">
                            <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("QuantityType.Code") %></ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_QuantityType" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_QuantityType" DataTextField="Code" DataValueField="Guid" runat="server">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_QuantityType" runat="server" ErrorMessage="QuantityType is Required." ControlToValidate="DropDownList_QuantityType" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_Unit" Text='<%# Bind("Unit") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Unit" Text='<%# Bind("Unit") %>' runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_Unit" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Unit is Required." ControlToValidate="TextBox_Unit" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_UnitGrid" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Code" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup = "ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxUnitValidatorBidItem_Grid" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UnitPrice">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_UnitPrice" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_UnitPrice" Text='<%# Bind("UnitPrice") %>' runat="server" MaxLength="9"/>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_UnitPrice" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Unit Price is Required." ControlToValidate="TextBox_UnitPrice" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator_UnitPrice" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Unit Price is in incorrect format or exceeds (999999.99)." ControlToValidate="TextBox_UnitPrice" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" ValidationExpression="^\d{0,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FHWA">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label_FHWA" Text='<%# Bind("FHWA") %>' runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_FHWA" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="true">Select FHWA</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Y</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="N">N</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_FHWA" runat="server" ErrorMessage="FHWA is Required." ControlToValidate="DropDownList_FHWA" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_IsActive" Checked='<%# Bind("IsActive") %>' runat="server" Enabled="False" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_IsActive" Checked='<%# Bind("IsActive") %>' runat="server" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel_AddBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <table width="35%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Code:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_CodeBidItemTypeTables" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_CodeBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Code is Required." ControlToValidate="TextBox_CodeBidItemTypeTables" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Enabled="false" CssClass="failureNotification"  SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_CodeBidItemTypeTables" ControlToValidate="TextBox_CodeBidItemTypeTables" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxCodeValidatorBidItem" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_DescriptionBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_DescriptionBidItemTypeTables" ControlToValidate="TextBox_DescriptionBidItemTypeTables" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxDescriptionValidatorBidItem" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Quantity Type:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_QuantityTypeBidItemTypeTables" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_QuantityType" DataTextField="Code" DataValueField="Guid" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="true">Select QuantityType</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_QuantityTypeBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="Quantity Type is Required." ControlToValidate="DropDownList_QuantityTypeBidItemTypeTables" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Unit:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_UnitBidItemTypeTables" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_UnitBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Unit is Required." ControlToValidate="TextBox_UnitBidItemTypeTables" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Enabled="false" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_UnitBidItemTypeTables" ControlToValidate="TextBox_UnitBidItemTypeTables" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxUnitValidatorBidItem" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>UnitPrice:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_UnitPriceBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" MaxLength="9"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_UnitPriceBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Unit Price is Required." ControlToValidate="TextBox_UnitPriceBidItemTypeTables" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Enabled="false" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator_UnitPriceBidItemTypeTables" ControlToValidate="TextBox_UnitPriceBidItemTypeTables" ClientIDMode="Static" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" Display="Dynamic" Enabled="true" CssClass="failureNotification" OnServerValidate="TextBoxUnitPriceValidatorBidItem" SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FHWA:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_FHWABidItemTypeTables" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="true">Select FHWA</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Y</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="N">N</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_FHWABidItemTypeTables" runat="server" Enabled="false" ErrorMessage="FHWA is Required." ControlToValidate="DropDownList_FHWABidItemTypeTables" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" CssClass="failureNotification">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button_AddBidItemTypeTables" runat="server" Text="Add" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ValidationFailed" OnClick="Button_AddBidItemTypeTables_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </asp:View>
```

Anyone experience similar issue before?

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `e.Row.FindControl` instead of `e.Row.Cells[e.Row.RowIndex].FindControl`.